# How calculates Units in crystal report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am creating a report for a fabric company.
Report contains two columns fabric ordered and unit as per order. Unit as per the order will be shown with respect to quality of fabric.
In my database I have columns to know fabric ordered i.e. ItemQty and grade(quality of fabric) , A grade can take values 'TAKA','SMALL TAKA','PCS' and 'SUIT LENGTH'.

My requirement is Units calculation:

In case of TAKA : 1 TAKA = 1 UNIT

In case of SMALL TAKA : 1 SMALL TAKA = 1 UNIT

In case of PCS : 10 PCS = 1 UNIT

In case of SUIT LENGTH :  3 SUIT LENGTH = 1 UNIT

So I am making the use of formula in crystal reports.

```
if {tableName.grade} = 'TAKA' then {tableName.ItemQty}
else if {tableName.grade} = 'SMALL TAKA' then {tableName.ItemQty}
else if {tableName.grade} = 'SUIT LENGTH' then {tableName.ItemQty}/3
else if {tableName.grade} = 'PCS' then {tableName.ItemQty}/10
```

I don't know why data is not coming properly. There is no errors I found in formula.

Comment: Do you get the wrong number of units? Elaborate on "data is not coming properly".

Comment: for some orders it is coming fine. the order which is combines of 'TAKA' and 'PCS' in that case it is not correct.

Comment: check the database for the names of `TAKA` and `PCS` I guess those may be inserted differently in database

Comment: I have checked database it is `TAKA` and `PCS`. That means my formula is correct, isn't it ?